Changing class weights in Yolov7
I have imbalanced dataset and that's why i want to change my class weights for under representeds. What should i do?
in loss.py i make these changes.But i don't know if have to make some changes in train.py or any other files.  
class ComputeLoss:
    def __init__(self, model, autobalance=False, class_weights=None):
        super(ComputeLoss, self).__init__()
        device = next(model.parameters()).device  # get model device
        h = model.hyp  # hyperparameters

        # Define criteria
        self.class_weights = class_weights.to(device) if class_weights is not None else None  # Store class weights

        BCEcls = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=self.class_weights) if self.class_weights is not None else nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=torch.tensor([h['cls_pw']], device=device))
        BCEobj = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=torch.tensor([h['obj_pw']], device=device))

        # Class label smoothing
        self.cp, self.cn = smooth_BCE(eps=h.get('label_smoothing', 0.0))  # positive, negative BCE targets

        # Focal loss
        g = h['fl_gamma']  # focal loss gamma
        if g > 0:
            BCEcls, BCEobj = FocalLoss(BCEcls, g), FocalLoss(BCEobj, g)

        det = model.module.model[-1] if is_parallel(model) else model.model[-1]  # Detect() module
        self.balance = {3: [4.0, 1.0, 0.4]}.get(det.nl, [4.0, 1.0, 0.25, 0.06, .02])  # P3-P7
        self.ssi = list(det.stride).index(16) if autobalance else 0  # stride 16 index
        self.BCEcls, self.BCEobj, self.gr, self.hyp, self.autobalance = BCEcls, BCEobj, model.gr, h, autobalance
        for k in 'na', 'nc', 'nl', 'anchors':
            setattr(self, k, getattr(det, k))

    def __call__(self, p, targets):  # predictions, targets, model
        device = targets.device
        lcls, lbox, lobj = torch.zeros(1, device=device), torch.zeros(1, device=device), torch.zeros(1, device=device)
        tcls, tbox, indices, anchors = self.build_targets(p, targets)  # targets

        # Losses
        for i, pi in enumerate(p):  # layer index, layer predictions
            b, a, gj, gi = indices[i]  # image, anchor, gridy, gridx
            tobj = torch.zeros_like(pi[..., 0], device=device)  # target obj

            n = b.shape[0]  # number of targets
            if n:
                ps = pi[b, a, gj, gi]  # prediction subset corresponding to targets

                # Regression
                pxy = ps[:, :2].sigmoid() * 2. - 0.5
                pwh = (ps[:, 2:4].sigmoid() * 2) ** 2 * anchors[i]
                pbox = torch.cat((pxy, pwh), 1)  # predicted box
                iou = bbox_iou(pbox.T, tbox[i], x1y1x2y2=False, CIoU=True)  # iou(prediction, target)
                lbox += (1.0 - iou).mean()  # iou loss

                # Objectness
                tobj[b, a, gj, gi] = (1.0 - self.gr) + self.gr * iou.detach().clamp(0).type(tobj.dtype)  # iou ratio

                # Classification
                if self.nc > 1:  # cls loss (only if multiple classes)
                    t = torch.full_like(ps[:, 5:], self.cn, device=device)  # targets
                    t[range(n), tcls[i]] = self.cp
                    lcls += self.BCEcls(ps[:, 5:], t)  # BCE

            obji = self.BCEobj(pi[..., 4], tobj)
            lobj += obji * self.balance[i]  # obj loss
            if self.autobalance:
                self.balance[i] = self.balance[i] * 0.9999 + 0.0001 / obji.detach().item()

        if self.autobalance:
            self.balance = [x / self.balance[self.ssi] for x in self.balance]
        lbox *= self.hyp['box']
        lobj *= self.hyp['obj']
        lcls *= self.hyp['cls']
        bs = tobj.shape[0]  # batch size

        loss = lbox + lobj + lcls
        return loss * bs, torch.cat((lbox, lobj, lcls, loss)).detach()

I have a dataset that some of classes are really less than others and i don't waste my time to increase the data in that class. So i need to do this, i hope you can help me!
